# Github page appears empty after pushing a flutter web app release version

Tags: flutter, github-pages, flutter-web

### The issue

I pushed the `release` version of my project by

`flutter build web --release`

and created a repo inside `./build/web` and pushed it on github.

The repo can be found here: https://github.com/Alexakis97/webappjs

Although when I visit  https://alexakis97.github.io/webappjs/ the app doesn't appear on the screen (it's just an empty page)

### What I've tried

I found a related post that suggested to change the `<base href="/">` although I am accessing it on the root directory.

Full notes in my `index.html`

```
 <!--
    If you are serving your web app in a path other than the root, change the
    href value below to reflect the base path you are serving from.

    The path provided below has to start and end with a slash "/" in order for
    it to work correctly.

    Fore more details:
    * https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base
  -->
```

Comment: I'm guessing you've just fixed it?

Comment: oh I see last commit was `<base href="/webappjs/">` in index.html so that must have the job done